# Indexing content using Core Spotlight

Tags: ios, corespotlight

In the Mail app or in the Messages app you can search for the content of any message using the Core Spotlight search. Also I can see OneNote doing this, so it should be available in APIs.

However, documentation about that is almost none existent. I can see only that in `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` there is `contentUrl`, but I have tried to set NSUrl of the .txt file and nothing happened. Also tried to set contentType to `kUTTypeText` and `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` but no improvements.

Is some specific file format required? Or something else one should do?

Comment: so your data is messages? what attributes are you setting values for currently? the subject or text content?

Comment: Why can't you just deeplink the .txt file in your app. I know this will be a hack for your case but, can solve your problem too. To deeplink, set the unique identifier and get it in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler{}` in AppDelegate.m

Comment: @Wain, data is stored by the user so in theory it can be any text, its usual length is around 5000 characters, though it can be any length. I set title and thumbnailUrl, if the item originates fromt the web I also set contentSources.

Comment: @SanchitKumarSingh I don't mind hacks, I already have some deeps links and I am using the API that you mention for those cases. However, I don't see how it could help. Do you refer to something like https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/deep-linking-your-nativescripts-apps-with-ios-9-user-activity-and-core-spotlight-apis ? I believe you should answer below, even if it is not a full solution for me if there is some useful information and is at least partial solution someone (including me) may vote for it.

Answer (score 7):

The [Apple documentation on CoreSpotlight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CoreSpotlight_Framework/) breaks down the process of creating and adding items to a searchable index:

> - Create a CSSearchableItemAttributeSet object and specify properties that describe the item you want to index.
> - Create a CSSearchableItem object to represent the item. A CSSearchableItem object has a unique identifier that lets you refer to
>     it later.
> - If needed, specify a domain identifier so that you can gather multiple items together and manage them as a group.
> - Associate the attribute set with the searchable item.
> - Add the searchable item to the index.

Here's a quick example I that shows how to index a simple Note class:

```
class Note {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage?

    init(title: String, description: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

Then in some other function, create your notes, create a `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` for each note, create a unique `CSSearchableItem` from the attribute set, and index the collection of searchable items:

```
import CoreSpotlight
import MobileCoreServices

// ...

// Build your Notes data source to index
var notes = [Note]()
notes.append(Note(title: "Grocery List", description: "Buy milk, eggs"))
notes.append(Note(title: "Reminder", description: "Soccer practice at 3"))
let parkingReminder = Note(title: "Reminder", description: "Soccer practice at 3")
parkingReminder.image = UIImage(named: "parkingReminder")
notes.append(parkingReminder)

// The array of items that will be indexed by CoreSpotlight
var searchableItems = [CSSearchableItem]()

for note in notes {
    // create an attribute set of type Text, since our reminders are text
    let searchableItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeText as String)

    // If we have an image, add it to the attribute set
    if let image = note.image {
        searchableItemAttributeSet.thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        // you can also use thumbnailURL if your image is coming from a server or the bundle
//        searchableItemAttributeSet.thumbnailURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("image", withExtension: "jpg")
    }

    // set the properties on the item to index
    searchableItemAttributeSet.title = note.title
    searchableItemAttributeSet.contentDescription = note.description

    // Build your keywords
    // In this case, I'm tokenizing the title of the note by a space and using the values returned as the keywords
    searchableItemAttributeSet.keywords = note.title.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    // create the searchable item
    let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "com.mygreatapp.notes" + ".\(note.title)", domainIdentifier: "notes", attributeSet: searchableItemAttributeSet)
}

// Add our array of searchable items to the Spotlight index
CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems(searchableItems) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        // handle failure
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This example has been adapted from [AppCoda's How To Use Core Spotlight Framework in iOS 9](http://www.appcoda.com/core-spotlight-framework/) guide.

Comment: I had some comments, but deleted them and done the experiment. In not so short email (18600 characters), EVERY word is searchable, including common ones like 'this'. I believe that it excludes using description and very likely excludes keywords too. Do you agree?

Comment: @IvanIčin it is possible OneNote has a list of pronouns or other blacklisted words which are stripped from the searchable text before creating an index of searchable items.